# Having trouble with Binary Search Static method cannot be referenced

Tags: java, compiler-errors, binary-search

The problem I face is understanding how to utilize the `binary search` to search a given `array`(movies) for a user input title?  I have a feel for the search itself but don't understand how to use the return value to display the title if found or not found.

The chuck of code that follows includes my `bubble sort` leading into the `binary search`.  Here are some of the errors message I keep seeing.

```
C:\Users\goofy bastard\Documents\JAVA>javac CharlieBrownP5.java
CharlieBrownP5.java:115: error: non-static method binarySearch(Movie[],String) 
cannot be referenced from a static context   
binarySearch(movies, key) = x;

CharlieBrownP5.java:115: error: unexpected type
 binarySearch(movies, key) = x;

  required: variable
  found:    value
CharlieBrownP5.java:134: error: cannot find symbol        if(key.comparTo(movies[mid].getTitle()) > 0) {
  symbol:   method comparTo(String)
  location: variable key of type String
3 errors
```

Code:

```
    public static void displayTotals(Movie[] movies) {
    double totalRevenue = 0;
    int totalMovies = Movie.getTotalMovies();
    for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        totalRevenue += movies[i].calcRevenue();
    }
    System.out.print("The total number of movies is " + totalMovies +
        " and their total revenue is ");
    System.out.printf("%8.3f", totalRevenue);
    System.out.print(" million dollars.\n\n");

}

public static void searchForMovie(Movie[] movies) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean needNextPass = true;
    String key;
    Movie temp;


    System.out.print("Enter the Title of the Movie to Search for: ");
    key = input.nextLine();

    for(int pass = 1; pass < movies.length && needNextPass; pass++)
    {
        needNextPass = false;
        for(int x=0; x< movies.length-pass; x++)
        {
            if(movies[x].getTitle().compareTo(movies[x+1].getTitle()) > 0)
            {
                temp = movies[x];
                movies[x] =  movies[x+1];
                movies[x+1] = temp;

                needNextPass = true;
            }
        }
    }
    int x;
    binarySearch(movies, key) = x;

    if (movies[x].getTitle() == key){
        System.out.printf(movies[x].toString());
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("There is no match item found for movie " +
            "with the title " + key);
    }
}

public static void getMenuChoice4() { 

}
public int binarySearch(Movie[] movies, String key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = movies.length -1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(key.comparTo(movies[mid].getTitle()) > 0) {
            high = mid -1;
        }
        else if(key == movies[mid].getTitle()){
            return mid;
        }
        else{
            low = mid + 1;
        }

    }   
    return -low - 1;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ive been at this for hours.
I am very new to java, this is part of an assignment for my java class.
Keep it simple please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all - `binarySearch` is not static, and you're trying to use it in a static function. Just make it static:

```
public static int binarySearch(Movie[] movies, String key) {
...
```

For the other error, you just need to swap the function call and variable around:

```
x = binarySearch(movies, key);
```

because `binarySearch(movies, key) = x;` means assign `x` to the value returned from the function (not the other way around), which doesn't make sense as the value returned disappears once that expression finished executing.

And you just typed `compareTo` wrong (missing the `e`).

Comment: Problem solved from there, had a few other errors pop up but manged to fix them.  Thanks for the speedy Response.